# Trying to deal with IO actions

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to deal with IO actions. I wonder why does this work:

```
main = do
  alias = getLine
  name <- alias
  putStrLn ("your name is: " ++ name)
```

saying

```
 parse error on input `='
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add keyword `let`

```
main = do
  let alias = getLine
  name <- alias
  putStrLn ("your name is: " ++ name)
```

`do` is a specified construction for monadic `bind` operator, it's not a `cosmic space`. All you write into block `do` is really chain of `>>=` monaidic functions. So you should use `let` construction.
But you can make alias in other part of you program.

```
alias = getLine

main = do
  name <- alias
  putStrLn ("your name is: " ++ name)
```

Comment: +1 for "cosmic space". This is the standard to which I will aspire in my Haskell code in the future.